# Number of digits in the decimal representation of the powers of 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that as $n$ runs through the positive integers, the *number of digits* in the decimal representation of the sequence of powers of $2$, the set $2, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots$ can assume *every* possibile positive integral value. It seems that the number of digits increases by $1$ at every fourth power. This seems believable because ${{\log_{10}}}2$ is about $0.3$. But I am trying to find a rigorous proof of the above statement.
Why is $2$ special? Why is this not the case for other positive integers like $13$ for instance.

Comment: 2 is not special: this happens for every number $n <10$. Indeed, the number of digits of $2^k$ is simply the floor of $k \log_{10} 2$. Since $\log_{10} 2 <1$, its multiples "cannot skip integers", for example they cannot skip from $3$ to $5$ without passing through $4$.

Comment: $2^{10}\approx 10^3$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ the number of digits of $2^n$. That means that $10^{d-1} \le 2^n < 10^d$.

Taking $\log_{10}$ we get $d-1 \le n \log_{10}(2)< d$ which leads to $d = \lfloor n \log_{10}(2)\rfloor + 1$ .

That explains the behavior you're observing. A similar formula can be derived for others numbers, there's nothing special about $2$ (or the base $10$).

Comment: To prove that all possible number of digits are actually attained, there is after all something special about the base $10$ and the fact that $2<10$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was talking about the behavior of increasing at a "quasi-linear" rate of the numbers of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Assume some fixed length $d$ representing the number of digits, and let's see if there exists some $k$ such that $2^k$ that has length $d$ when expanded.

The number of digits of $2^k$ is equal to $\lfloor\log_{10}(2^k)\rfloor + 1$.

$\lfloor\log_{10}(2^k)\rfloor + 1 = d$

$\lfloor\log_{10}(2^k)\rfloor = d - 1$

$d - 1 \leq \log_{10}(2^k) \lt d$

$d - 1 \leq k \log_{10}(2) \lt d$

$\frac{d - 1}{\log_{10}(2)} \leq k \lt \frac{d}{\log_{10}(2)}$

So $k$ can take on an integral value for sure if the size of that range is at least of size $1$.

And since $\frac{d}{\log_{10}(2)} - \frac{d - 1}{\log_{10}(2)} = \log_2(10) = 3.32...$, the threshold will always be greater than $1$, which means there will exist an integral value for $k$ regardless of what $d$ is, assuming we're dealing with base $2$ numbers.

It would stop working for base $b$ once we have $\log_{b}(10) < 1$, which begins once $b > 10$.

Comment: You must mean $$\frac {d}{{\log}_{10} 2} - \frac {d-1}{{\log}_{10} 2}  = \frac {1} {{\log}_{10} 2} = 3.32...$$ I get the point though-thanks!

Comment: @student $\frac{1}{\log_{10}(2)}$ is the same as $\log_{2}(10)$ (the variables swap places), the latter just a little easier to read / deal with

Comment: I missed the exchange of 2and10! Sorry.